# SQL Server error while trying to insert data to database on a linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, dbf

I'm trying to insert some data to a database on a linked server but I'm getting the #215 error.

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO DBF...mone0012
   ('CODE', 'TIMES', 'BANK', 'INTCODE', 'AGENCY', 'DATE', 'DUE', 'VALUE', 
    'DISCOUNT', 'PAY', 'PDATE', 'OVER', 'ODATE', 'DOC', 'TYPE', 'EMITT', 'SIT', 
    'BUS', 'CLIENT', 'DEALER', 'LAST', 'DEVBACK', 'DESCONTADO', 'VENDOR', 'FRETE',
    'DATEB', 'TIPOC', 'OLDCLI', 'DESPESA', 'DESPDATE', 'DUPALOC', 'SACADO', 
    'CODSACADO', 'BXREAL', 'BXCONT', 'BXTERC', 'BXARBIT', 'DATAPAG', 'BANKANT', 
    'PROTESTO', 'ENDOSSO', 'SITENDOSSO', 'REEMBOLSO', 'CREDITO', 'ACERTO', 'DESPBANC', 
    'DESPCART', 'JUROS', 'DESPBANCP', 'DESPCARTP', 'JUROSP', 'LIQCNAB', 'NCOMIS', 
    'SEQRELATO', 'DEBINCOB', 'TXGER', 'TXVENDOR', 'COMPGER', 'COMPDEALER',  
    'COMPVENDOR', 'COMGER', 'COMDEALER', 'COMVENDOR', 'CODSEQ', 'COMPDEALE2', 
    'EMITCUSTOD', 'CONTRATO', 'SEND', 'BUSCDEB', 'SENDDATE', 'SENDTYPE', 'QUITEMIT', 
    'CONTRLOC', 'TXDEALER') 
VALUES 
   ('09431500A', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-02-23 10:55:00.000', 
    '2012-02-23 10:55:00.000', 2500.50, 0, 2500.50, '2012-02-23 10:55:00.000', 0, 
    NULL, 'd', 0, NULL, 'D', '06', '6666', '666', NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 
    NULL, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)
```

Error:

> Msg 215, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Parameters supplied for object 'DBF...mone0012' which is not a function. If the parameters are intended as a table hint, a WITH keyword is required.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "DBF" here? A DBase file? Foxpro?

Comment: We don´t know. Following the steps of the 3rd reply of [this link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=562518) we found that the files is `3 Foxbase/Foxpro/dBaseIII/IV/V no memo`. But exactly what we don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the 3 dots are the problem. I always use:

```
insert into [LINKED_SERVER].DB.SCHEMA.TABLE
select * from TABLE
```

try updating with your information

also, I dont think you need single quotes on the names of the columns after the insert

Comment: I've tried to insert without specifying the column names and worked. The problem is the number of columns, which is big and I just want to insert some values...

Comment: i dont think the number of columns matter. I think it was the quotes. Can you test it? It would be good to know

Comment: Yeah. It works. Now I've another problem. I have columns which are named with functions of MS SQL. How to solve this problem?

Comment: use [NAME] (again, without the quotes)

Comment: Thanks. Now just to realize. MS SQL escape tables and columns with [], right?

Comment: you can use [] to specify the exact name of the object. If you have a table called My Table (with spaces) you will have to access it with []. Same logic for objects named as reserved words or when you have a sensitive case on the object's name

Answer (score 0):

Try putting [] around your table name. I would guess that '...' might be confusing it.

```
INSERT INTO [DBF...mone0012]
('CODE',        'TIMES',    'BANK', 'INTCODE',  'AGENCY',   'DATE',                     'DUE',                      'VALUE',    'DISCOUNT', 'PAY',      'PDATE',                    'OVER', 'ODATE',    'DOC',  'TYPE', 'EMITT',    'SIT',  'BUS',  'CLIENT',   'DEALER',   'LAST', 'DEVBACK',  'DESCONTADO',   'VENDOR',   'FRETE',    'DATEB',    'TIPOC',    'OLDCLI',   'DESPESA',  'DESPDATE', 'DUPALOC',  'SACADO',   'CODSACADO',    'BXREAL',   'BXCONT',   'BXTERC',   'BXARBIT',  'DATAPAG',  'BANKANT',  'PROTESTO', 'ENDOSSO',  'SITENDOSSO',   'REEMBOLSO',    'CREDITO',  'ACERTO',   'DESPBANC', 'DESPCART', 'JUROS',    'DESPBANCP',    'DESPCARTP',    'JUROSP',   'LIQCNAB',  'NCOMIS',   'SEQRELATO',    'DEBINCOB', 'TXGER',    'TXVENDOR', 'COMPGER',  'COMPDEALER',   'COMPVENDOR',   'COMGER',   'COMDEALER',    'COMVENDOR',    'CODSEQ',   'COMPDEALE2',   'EMITCUSTOD',   'CONTRATO', 'SEND', 'BUSCDEB',  'SENDDATE', 'SENDTYPE', 'QUITEMIT', 'CONTRLOC', 'TXDEALER') VALUES
('09431500A',   1,          NULL,   NULL,       NULL,       '2012-02-23 10:55:00.000',  '2012-02-23 10:55:00.000',  2500.50,    0,          2500.50,    '2012-02-23 10:55:00.000',  0,      NULL,       'd',    0,      NULL,       'D',    '06',   '6666',     '666',      NULL,   0,          NULL,           NULL,       0,          NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       0,          NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       NULL,           NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       0,          NULL,       NULL,           0,              0,          0,          NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       NULL,           NULL,           NULL,       0,          0,          NULL,           0,          0,          0,          0,          0,              0,              0,          0,              0,              NULL,       NULL,           0,              NULL,       NULL,   NULL,       NULL,       NULL,       0,          NULL,       NULL)
```

Comment: Didn't work. When using [DBF...mone0012] returns the following error: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'DBF...mone0012'.` And when using [DBF]...[mone0012] returns the same error before.

Comment: Ok, have to ask, is DBF...mone0012 the actual name of the table?

Comment: DBF is the linked server and the mone0012 is the table.